# how to filter strings in nested array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a search function that returns find which has search word in the specified array. Let's say, a collection has [aa, ab, aaa], and search word is "a". In this case, return the object to display. Because at least one of the strings in the array has 'a'.

dataStructure

```
[
  {
   name:'aa',
   searchWords:['aa','ab','bc'] <- I want to use this array for search
  },
  {
   name:'bb',
   searchWords:['bb','bc','de'] <- I want to use this array for search
  },
...
]
```

I tried to fix the issue, by using includes(), filter(),indexOf(). However still it returns nothing or returns data when the search word is exactly matched.
How to fix the code to achieve aiming?
Thank you in advance!

**this part works well**

```
let filterStudents = students;
if (searchName.length > 0 && searchTag.length === 0) {
  filterStudents = students.filter((student) => {
    if (
      student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchName.toLowerCase())
      || student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchName.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
```

**Problem happens on this part**

```
} else if (searchName.length === 0 && searchTag.length > 0) {
  filterStudents = students.filter(
    (student) => {
      console.log(student.tags);
      student.tags.filter((tag) => {
        console.log(tag);
        tag.indexOf(searchTag) > -1;
      });
    },
  );
} else if (searchName.length > 0 && searchTag.length > 0) {
} else {
  console.log('both');
}
```

Comment: There is a `return` missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `return` from the `filter` callbacks

As a sidenote, there is also `String#includes`:

```
filterStudents = students.filter(student =>
  student.tags.some((tag) => tag.includes(searchTag))
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I followed the advice by this code. However it still does not work.

     else if (searchName.length === 0 && searchTag.length > 0) {
      filterStudents = students.filter((student) => student.tags.some((tag) => tag.includes(searchTag)));

Comment: Sorry. I just find solution. adding .toLowerCase() make this serch works.
      filterStudents = students.filter((student) => student.tags.some((tag) => tag.includes(searchTag.toLowerCase())));

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to search for matches when the corresponding `searchTag` or `searchName` is filled out, use the conditional operator inside the `filter` callback to check whether the filter test should be carried out:

```js
const students = [
  {
   name:'aa',
   searchWords:['aa','ab','bc']
  },
  {
   name:'bb',
   searchWords:['bb','bc','de']
  },
];
const doFilter = () => {
  const [searchName, searchTag] = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
    .map(input => input.value.toLowerCase());
  const filtered = students.filter(({ name, searchWords }) => (
    (searchName ? name.toLowerCase().includes(searchName) : true) &&
    (searchTag ? searchWords.some(word => word.toLowerCase().includes(searchTag)) : true)
  ));
  code.textContent = JSON.stringify(filtered);
};

window.addEventListener('change', doFilter);
```

```html
<input placeholder="searchName">
<input placeholder="searchTag">
<div>
  <code id="code"></code>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is a right way. I have a question, and I have four conditions that come from a combination of True and False of Name and Tag. In this case, Should I go with this way?

Comment: As in, in addition to checking whether the search strings have length, you also want to check for inclusion *or* check for negation of both strings? At that point, it's too much to fit into the single callback expression readably - better to put the two tests into variables first, and then return the variables or their negations, conditionally, based on those other flags

Comment: RE: your deleted comment, that's already present in the answer - `searchWords.some(word => word.toLowerCase().includes(searchTag))` where `searchTag` is already lower-cased (see the `.map` callback)